# Tile element over page for mass printing of stickers

Tags: printing, inkscape

I have downloaded [ECB hazard symbols](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/ECB_hazard_symbols) from wikipedia in order to print them on paper and stick them on whatever chemicals I am storing.

How can I tile them over the A4 page using Inkscape? Pasting them all over does not look very good:
[image: tiled image in Inkscape]

It would be best to have a dashed guides along the page marking the place for scissors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool intended for this is *Create Tiled Clones:*

1. Place one symbol in the upper left of your sheet.
2. *Edit → Clone → Create Tiled Clones.*
3. *Reset* (bottom left; not needed, if you never used this).
4. Go to the *Shift* tab, and use something like the following to acquire some gap between the symbols:
   [image]

   If you wish to optimally use your sheet, this requires some trial-and-error adjustment of the shift percentages.
5. Select the appropriate number of rows and columns.
6. *Create*

Alternatively:

1. Place one symbol in the upper left.
2. Create the right number of symbols for one row using *Duplicate* or *Clone.*
3. Place one symbol in the upper right.
4. Use one of the horizontal distribution tools from *Align and Distribute Objects,* e.g., *Make horizontal gaps between objects equal.* After this, you should now have one perfect row.
5. *Group* the row.
6. Repeat steps 2 to 4 with rows instead of individual symbols and vertically instead of horizontally.
7. Ungroup everything (for the scissor marks).

For the scissor marks:

1. Create one vertical line of appropriate length.
2. Go to the *Stroke style* tab of *Fill and Stroke* and select the desired dashes and stroke width.
3. Place that line somewhere between the first and the second column.
4. Select one symbol from the first and second column each (it does not matter which) and the line.
5. Use *Make horizontal gaps between objects equal* from *Align and Distribute.* The line should now be in position.
6. Adjust the position of that line vertically (e.g. by *Centre on horizontal axis* with *Relative to:* being set to *Page.* (All from *Align and Distribute*).
7. Clone or Duplicate that line such that you have as many vertical lines as needed.
8. Move one of the results somewhere between the last and second-to-last column holding *Control* (to keep the vertical position).
9. Repeat steps 4 and 5 with that line.
10. Select all lines.
11. Use *Make horizontal gaps between objects equal* from *Align and Distribute.* The lines should now be in position.
12. Repeat with the horizontal lines.

Comment: This is really brilliant answer, can't wait to test it all! But I already have a question: How do I position my element to the upper left corner? I failed to get it totally upper left which has resulted in uneven horizontal/vertical spaces.

Comment: The problem is that the exact answer depends on your printer’s margins and how you print it (scale to printable area, as it is, etc.). If your document proportions match the proportions of your printed area and you print accordingly, you can use aligning in respect to page. I do not see however how failing to put something exactly in a corner results in uneven spaces.

Comment: I'm talking about the corner of the Inkscape document.

Comment: Then align in respect to page: *Align and Distribute:* Select *Page* for *Relative to,* select your object, *Align left edges* and *Align top edges.*